# Not able to import Header.jsx properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am not able to import Header.jsx in App.js when App.js and Header.jsx are on same level using import Header from "./Header.jsx"; but when I am keeping Header.jsx inside components folder , I am not able to import it in App.js even though I am using :   import Header from "./components/Header" inside App.js

App.js(working)

```
import './App.css';

//components
import Header from "./Header.jsx";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Header/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.js(not working)

```
import './App.css';

//components
import Header from ".components/Header.jsx";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Header/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I don't know why is it not able to detect the relative path

Comment: note you are missing the "/" forward slash. use "import Header from "./components/Header.jsx";"

Answer (score 0):

This is the way ReactJS works, it won't be able to detect relative path like other languages such as Java and Python. And, you don't need to mention Jsx at the end of component name. If you would like to import Header from the component folder, Here is the example.

```
import './App.css';

//components
import Header from "./components/Header";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Header/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This code should work but I think your explanation is wrong, react does work with relative paths. It does not detect absolute file paths but even this you can configure.